# String return limit in napi

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-addon-api

I want to port some C++ code to js using napi (node-addon-api). The code is a search handler that returns string. So I wanted to know if there is any size limit in napi in returning strings?

Answer (score 0):

No obvious limit that I know of.
But if you are going to pass really long strings, the copying from native to Javascript heap would kill the performance. You may consider use buffer-like types to pass the address of underlying data.

Refer to [Using Buffers to share data between Node.js and C++ - Scott Frees](https://community.risingstack.com/using-buffers-node-js-c-plus-plus/) for detail.

Related N-API: https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_create_buffer